# Should I first stop all local servers running on localhost before starting Tor?

Tags: security, server

If I have apache/mysql and the PHP built-in server running on localhost, should I first stop the local server before starting Tor, or is it totally safe? As in, can someone access my computer/sever/whatever if I connect to Tor while my local server is running?

PS: It's just a regular server I use for developing sites for work, not a hidden service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you edit your tor configuration (your `torrc` file) to add an onion service, tor won't run any onion services and no one will be able to connect to any of your local servers, so you're safe. Even if you accidentally set up a v3 onion service, anyone who wishes to connect to your service would need to know the full 32-byte public identity key of the service in order to connect.